# Como corregir No me permite modificar android:layout_height en un LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

estoy tratando de cambiar el alto en que se mostraría las filas que se verían en un **ExpandableListView**, sin embargo aunque he modificado el atributo **android:layout_height** con diferentes valóres, al emular no se notan los cambios, es como si siempre estuviera **"wrap_content"**, son dos Layouts y con ambos pasa igual, si a alguien sabe como solucionarlo, agradezco la ayuda.

A continuacion lo xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ccaa4c">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_cate_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000f61"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Categoria" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_cate_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0.8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0.8dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#142a46">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_scate_icon"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="SubCategoria" />
```

Comment: Es ese todo el contenido del layout? O falta algo mas? Agrega todo el contenido relevante si esperas una respuesta.

Comment: @Einer Si solo eso, ya lo otro sería los códigos java, son dos layous con LinearLayou ambos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He solucionado esto agregando dentro de cada Layout un `LinearLayout` y a estos les coloqué margen:

`android:layout_marginTop="7dp"`
y
 `android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"`

con esto logré que se viera mas amplio cada fila:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0.8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0.8dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#142a46">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_scate_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="SubCategoria" />

</LinearLayout>
```